# How do I insert radiobutton values in SQLite database using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qradiobutton

I am very new to programming.
I wanted to insert the values of my radiobutton into SQLite database
but still doesn't found the right way to do it.
The program consist 9 radiobutton, which is 1-3,4-5,6-7 and 8-9 in 4 different grouping/layout.
Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mejr.png),

```
   void lifestyle::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
   {
       QSqlQuery myqry;

       myqry.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lifestyle (Drinking VARCHAR(15), "
                  "Exercise VARCHAR(15), Smoking VARCHAR(10), Diet VARCHAR(10)) ");
            if(!myqry.exec())
            qDebug()<<myqry.lastError();
       else
            qDebug()<<"Table Created!";

       QString drinking= ui->radioButton_1->text();
       QString exercise = ui->radioButton_5->text();
       QString smoking = ui->radioButton_7->text();
       QString diet = ui->radioButton_8->text();

       myqry.prepare("INSERT INTO Lifestyle(Drinking, Exercise, Smoking, Diet) "
                  "values('"+drinking+"','"+exercise+"','"+smoking+"','"+diet+"')");

       if(myqry.exec()){
        ui->labelstat->setText("The information has been saved");

       }
       else{
        ui->labelstat->setText("Information failed to saved");

   }
   }
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here exactly, but you should read up on using prepared queries. It may not matter in this particular use case, but building SQL queries through string concatenation is not a good practice.

Comment: You need to tell us what data types you used in your database for those fields. But also MrEricSir is correct about your prepare statements.

Answer (score 0):

As some people have commented it appears the issue is in the prepared statements.  The first prepared statement does not need to be a prepared statement, because you don't use any c++ variables in the query.  Try rewriting the first query like this, and leave out the first  myqry.prepare.

```
if(!myqry.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lifestyle (Drinking VARCHAR(15), "
              "Exercise VARCHAR(15), Smoking VARCHAR(10), Diet VARCHAR(10)) "))
```

The second query should use a prepared statement.  Qt supports several methods for binding to prepared statements (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html).  The way I recommend is the following:

```
myqry.prepare("INSERT INTO Lifestyle(Drinking, Exercise, Smoking, Diet) "
              "values(:drink,:exercise,:smoke,:diet)");
myqry.bindValue(":drink",drinking);
myqry.bindValue(":exercise",exercise);
myqry.bindValue(":smoke",smoking);
myqry.bindValue(":diet",diet);
```

Then you can call myqry.exec() and continue on with the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the checked radio buttons, use the isChecked() method.

```
QString drinking = "";
QString exercise = "";
QString smoking = "";
QString diet = "";

if (ui->radioButton_1->isChecked()) {
  drinking = ui->radioButton_1->text();
}

if (ui->radioButton_5->isChecked()) {
  exercise = ui->radioButton_5->text();
}

if (ui->radioButton_7->isChecked()) {
  smoking = ui->radioButton_7->text();
}

if (ui->radioButton_8->isChecked()) {
  diet = ui->radioButton_8->text();
}

myqry.prepare("INSERT INTO Lifestyle(Drinking, Exercise, Smoking, Diet) "
              "values(:drink,:exercise,:smoke,:diet)");
myqry.bindValue(":drink",drinking);
myqry.bindValue(":exercise",exercise);
myqry.bindValue(":smoke",smoking);
myqry.bindValue(":diet",diet);
myqry.exec();
```

I don't know much about your application, but if multiple radio buttons can be selected, it might make more sense for you to use QCheckBox instead of radio buttons.  The methods (functions) used here are the same for radio buttons and check boxes.